# connect.send (form) , don't send

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

sorry about my english. I have a problem with AJAX about one week, and can't solve it. I have Searched everywere. This is part of code of login.js function. I don't know why it don't work

..

```
connect.open("POST","ajax.php?mode=login",true);
connect.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
window.alert(form); //here I see the window,with the data form ok
connect.send(form);
```

...

The path of ajax.php it's right, I put a message at the begining of ajax.php to check, but never execute.

ajax.php code...

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
switch (isset($_GET['mode']) ? $_GET['mode'] : null)  
 {        
case 'login':             
echo "login case";        
  break;       

default:           
  header('location: index.php');
 break;        
}
} 
else
{    
  header('location: index.php');  
 }
?>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How do you define the `form` variable?

Comment: "but never execute" — What never executes? How can you tell?

Comment: Sorry  my english bad, I try to say "never execute" becouse, never run ajax.php. I put a in ajax.php  var_dump($_POST); after <?php.. and nothing is displayed. Thank you..

Comment: form is defined: var  form, user, pass, sesion;
    user = __('user').value;
    pass = __('pass').value;
    sesion = __('session').checked ? true : false;
    form = 'user=' + user + '&pass=' + pass + '&sesion=' + sesion; I have a function __() : function __(id)
{ return document.getElementById(id);}

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line of your PHP file to `if (!empty($_POST)) {`

$_POST is never parsed to `true`, so your request always stops there. By using `!empty` you make sure there's a $_POST array, and that it's not empty.

Comment: That's not (completely) correct. `$_POST` will evaluate to `true` if it's not empty.

Comment: Ok thank you.. previusly to the "if" sentence, I had puted an echo before the "if", ... and I realized never arrive to  this file ( ajax.php), but I used your suggestion "if (!empty($_POST))" and don't works.
In my little experience...I'm realiazing the connect.send( ) , don't send nothing, and I don't know how to see. Thank you again.